# Send email to specific users .net core web app

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, sendgrid

I'm trying to send notification emails using SendGrid to users who have the same movie category preference in their profile, when a new movie is created. But it seems my code is not able to retrieve the data.

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Name,Description,Actors,Producers,Age,Duration,Date,Price,ImageFile,CategoriaId")] Filme filme)
    {


        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            
            string wwwRootPath = _hostEnvironment.WebRootPath;
            string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filme.ImageFile.FileName);
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(filme.ImageFile.FileName);
            filme.ImageName = fileName = fileName + DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssfff") + extension;
            string path = Path.Combine(wwwRootPath + "/Image/", fileName);
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
            {
                await filme.ImageFile.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
            }
            //Insert record
            _context.Add(filme);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            
            var getUserEmail = _context.Perfils.Include(a=>a.Email).Where(a=> a.CategoriaId == 1).ToListAsync();
      
                await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(getUserEmail.ToString(), "New Movie",
                    "New movie added");
            

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        ViewData["CategoriaId"] = new SelectList(_context.Categoria, "Id", "Name", filme.CategoriaId);
        return View(filme);
    }
```

Comment: Are you awaiting the email query?

Comment: What data is not retrieved? The users from the database, the film from the input binding, the image, or something else? Do you get an exception?

Comment: Seems you forgot to await `getUserEmail`. So the `getUserEmail.ToString()` wil result in something like `”System.Threading.Task<string…”`

Comment: I want to retrieve the email data from every user who has the "CategoriaId = 1" , but i don't get any exception

Answer (score 0):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

Both Jasen and Vincent Bitter have suggested that you are not awaiting your async request to get the email data. I'd also suggest that you should be looping through that data once you have received it to send to each email address.

Try something like this instead:

```cs
var userEmails = await _context.Perfils.Include(a=>a.Email).Where(a=> a.CategoriaId == 1).ToListAsync();

foreach (var email in userEmails) {
    await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(email.ToString(), "New Movie", "New movie added");
}
```

I'm not a C# developer, so that may be wrong and there may be a better way to perform an asynchronous action for every item in the loop. But hopefully that gives you an idea.